# How to get sum for different time period in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sum

query 1:

```
SELECT SUM(duration) FROM table_name WHERE timestart >= past24hours
```

query 2:

```
SELECT SUM(duration) FROM table_name WHERE timestart >= past7days
```

Hi all, i want to combined above two query and get sum in query.
Any way to do this?

Currently i have 2 more query in addition to above for past 30 days and 365 days.

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union`

like

```
SELECT SUM(duration) FROM table_name WHERE timestart >= past24hours
UNION
SELECT SUM(duration) FROM table_name WHERE timestart >= past7days
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(duration), 1 FROM table_name WHERE timestart >= '$date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
UNION
SELECT SUM(duration), 2 FROM table_name WHERE timestart BETWEEN '$date' - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND '$date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

this way you wont get rows with timestart in last 24 hours twice

Comment: My requirement is to get the result from selected date.

Comment: or for the purpose of testing you can change '$date' with other date. for example '2014-04-23'

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get all sums with different alias is as

```
select
t.sum1,t.sum2
from(
select 
 sum(case when timestart >= past24hours then duration END) as sum1,
 sum(case when timestart >= past7days then duration END) as sum2  
 from table_name
)t
```

You can add any number of sums within the query and give an alias name and add them in the select list so that they could be parsed later with your server side script.

With `UNION` it will return the same `column/alias`. When you have same sum value in `UNION` it will get only one and to get rid of it you can use `UNION ALL`